# How to move my fridge for easier cleaning?

Tags: refrigerator

I'd like to be able to move my fridge easily so I can clean under/in back of it. I got these "sliders" for it [ez moves](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005FGAP7W)

and put them under the fridge, but since the fridge has casters, the casters just "rolled off" the sliders. I tried using the sliders different ways (with just the plastic part or just the felt/rubber part), but it was the same problem. Even though the fridge has casters already, it is hard to move. Is there a way to improve the casters it already has? Or is there a better way to use the sliders? Or should I use something else under the casters, like something cup-shaped? Thanks:)

Comment: What type flooring is under the fridge?

Comment: It's that cheap-seeming vinyl-y tile stuff. I'm sure that's the technical term.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38HJVvHAdW0.  I use thin plywood under fridge rollers to protect vinyl or hardwood floors

Answer (score 2):

On some refrigerators the casters are adjustable up and down.

There is what looks like a bolt head or the top of a screw that you can turn with the appropriate tool that will raise or lower the casters. You may or may not have to remove the grill at the bottom of the fridge that covers the casters to access them.

Whether or not yours has this option,  Emptying the fridge will help greatly in allowing it to move better.

Comment: Also note that the refrigerator should be nearly level after adjusting the casters. A small "tilt-back" would assist the door to semi-automatically close.

Answer (score 0):

Cups should work well. Go for cheap disposable cups so that it doesn't matter that the fridge smashes them.